# remove Bootstrap responsive resolution less than 1000px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2.2

I'm currently developing a Web application using Bootstrap (latest) Dashboard sample : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/ , as you can when you open this sample and resize the browser to a width less than 767px the list on the left side disappear, 
http://im66.gulfup.com/XemFyZ.png
So my goal is to change bootstrap so that it have a minimum width of 1000px so it (Application) can not apply the responsive of mobile and tablet BUT in the same time still adapt with larger screen. and the left list always appear.

Note that I already search here but nothing help

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first so be default it is going to attempt to be responsive down to the smallest window size set. There are many ways to address your needs, the simplest without getting into LESS compiling (which would be the best way to do it) is to use the Bootstrap customization tool and set your screen widths before building your unique install of Bootstrap.

**Media Query Breakpoints**
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints